# Organization of code for a game using SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

I've been using SDL for some days now, and I decided after following some tutorials to start developing my own clone of Galaga. However, I had some difficulty trying to find a proper layout for my code.

For example, I have a Spaceship class defined as follows:

```
class Spaceship : public Sprite
{
public:
    Spaceship(SDL_Surface *surface);
    Spaceship(const char *filename);

    void handleEvent(SDL_Event *event);
};
```

where Sprite is a base class that holds the position on the screen and so on.
My constructor would be something like:

```
Spaceship::Spaceship(SDL_Surface *surface) :
    Sprite(surface)
{
    m_y = Game::screenHeight() - m_surface->h; //positions the ship at the bottom
}
```

From what I've seen it's not possible to use Game::screenWidth() [static class] because I'd need to include "game.h", which is basically the main game class and includes "spaceship.h", creating basically an infinite loop (I've tried using #ifndef etc. with no success).

Is it possible to achieve this kind of result?

**EDIT:** I found a way to overcome the problem (I just added the "game.h" include in the cpp file and not in the header file).

Comment: I generally solve the "main game class" problem by avoiding a "main game class".  One way to solve this is to let your *main function* instantiate all the items you need, then use the Dependency Injection to pass just the bits each class needs into each class, rather than relying on static state (effectively global variables).

Comment: "How do I design a project" is a pretty broad question, but you are basically doing things right (there's really no right/wrong way to design code when doing a learning project)

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Thanks, I'll evaluate this approach too

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to store pointers or references to those objects, then you can forward-declare one or both of the classes with `class Game;` or `class Spaceship;`.  This is also fine if they take these objects as parameters or return them (with some exceptions, afaik).

If you actually want both to have a member of the other, then this is *not* possible, as each object would then have a copy of itself inside it.

Comment: I don't know of any exception to receiving or returning incomplete types.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break a cycle in your dependency graph.

For example, one can add a field to your Spaceship class which saves a screen height.

Comment: I already thought about that, but it would be a problem in case I'd like to change the screen resolution during the game.

Comment: @Narrakan My own inclination, if I were in your situation, would be to place in Spaceship classes a link (reference) to some instance of settings class.